# How to access a nested element, passing array with coordinates

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

Is there any short way to access an element of a nested array, passing the array with coordinates? I mean something like:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
array = [1,1]

matrix [array]
# => 6
```

I just wonder if there is a shorter version than:

```
matrix [array[0]][array[1]]
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: this is ruby language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.inject(matrix, :fetch)
# => 6
```

Comment: @Volker: How does this not answer the question? This is a complete, correct, and idiomatic answer to the question, even though it is a bit on the short side. The only slight improvement to make it even more idiomatic would be to use `:[]` instead of `:fetch`, since `fetch` is generally only used when passing the optional default value.

Comment: at least an short explanation around the simple code piece will help the questioner as well as others to understand the answer better. So an overall improved experience for the site. This is why I set the flag when reviewing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use the [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class:

```
require 'matrix'

arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
matrix = Matrix[*arr] #=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]] 
matrix[1,1]           #=> 6 
matrix.row(1)         #=> Vector[5, 6, 7, 8] 
c = matrix.column(1)  #=> Vector[2, 6] 
c.to_a                #=> [2, 6] 
m = matrix.transpose  #=> Matrix[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]] 
m.to_a                #=> [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Comment: And if you happen to have a the indicies in an array, you can do `matrix[*indicies]`

Comment: @CameronMartin, yes, if `indices = [1,1]`, `matrix[*indices] => matrix[*[1,1]] => matrix[1,1]`, which is what I have above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix[1][1]
```

should equal 6.  matrix[1] is the 2nd array, matrix[1][1] is the second element in that array.

Comment: I know...

i wanted to ask about short and simple way to access matrix using array like...

matrix[array] or matrix.array or something similar

Comment: i don't want to use constraints, i want to use array object